# How many different area codes are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

In a different plan for area​ codes, the first digit could be any number from 0 through​ 5, the second digit was either 4,5,6 or​ 7, and the third digit could be any number except 5 and 7. With this​ plan, how many different area codes are​ possible?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should show us what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this website.

Answer (score 1):

Since the digits for each place are independent of each other, you can use multiplication. Namely, multiply the number of ways you can set the 1st digit by the number of ways you can set the 2nd digit by the number of ways you can set the 3rd digit.

There are 6 options for the 1st digit, 4 for the 2nd, and 8 for the 3rd.

So, there are $6 \times 4 \times 8$, or 192 different area codes.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, we discourage answers to questions that show no evidence of any independent effort to reach a solution.

Comment: @RobertShore Noted.